React component only rendering properly on first load
I’m setting up a web app using react but I’m currently having issues with my nav bar. I’m using the mantine UI library, the problem is as follows: on the first ever load of the web app the nav bar works correctly but after the site is refreshed it ends up looking weird like it’s not applying the css correctly. The only way to get it normal again is to remove my navbar file out of components and back in, but this only works for the first visit and once refreshed it goes back to being weird again. I am completely stumped and have tried everything to my knowledge, if anyone has experienced this before or knows how to help please do so.
React:
import React from 'react';
import { Group, Code, ScrollArea, rem } from '@mantine/core';
import {
  IconNotes,
  IconCalendarStats,
  IconGauge,
  IconPresentationAnalytics,
  IconFileAnalytics,
  IconAdjustments,
  IconLock,
} from '@tabler/icons-react';
import { UserButton } from './UserButton/UserButton';
import { LinksGroup } from './NavbarLinksGroup/NavbarLinksGroup';
import logo from '../assets/logo.png';
import classes from './NavbarNested.module.css';

const mockdata = [
  { label: 'Dashboard', icon: IconGauge },
  {
    label: 'Transactions',
    icon: IconNotes,
    initiallyOpened: true,
    links: [
      { label: 'Overview', link: '/' },
      { label: 'Forecasts', link: '/' },
      { label: 'Outlook', link: '/' },
      { label: 'Real time', link: '/' },
    ],
  },
  { label: 'Accounting', icon: IconCalendarStats },
  { label: 'Analytics', icon: IconPresentationAnalytics },
  { label: 'Company', icon: IconFileAnalytics },
  { label: 'Settings', icon: IconAdjustments },
];

export function NavbarNested() {
  const links = mockdata.map((item) => <LinksGroup {...item} key={item.label} />);

  return (
    <nav className={classes.navbar}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <Group justify="space-between">
          <img src={logo} alt="Logo" style={{ width: rem(50) }} />
          <Code fw={700}>v3.1.2</Code>
        </Group>
      </div>

      <ScrollArea className={classes.links}>
        <div className={classes.linksInner}>{links}</div>
      </ScrollArea>

      <div className={classes.footer}>
        <UserButton />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

CSS:
.navbar {
  background-color: light-dark(var(--mantine-color-white), var(--mantine-color-dark-6));
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  padding: var(--mantine-spacing-md);
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid light-dark(var(--mantine-color-gray-3), var(--mantine-color-dark-4));
}

.header {
  padding: var(--mantine-spacing-md);
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-left: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
  margin-right: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
  color: light-dark(var(--mantine-color-black), var(--mantine-color-white));
  border-bottom: 1px solid light-dark(var(--mantine-color-gray-3), var(--mantine-color-dark-4));
}

.links {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
  margin-right: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
}

.linksInner {
  padding-top: var(--mantine-spacing-xl);
  padding-bottom: var(--mantine-spacing-xl);
}

.footer {
  margin-left: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
  margin-right: calc(var(--mantine-spacing-md) * -1);
  border-top: 1px solid light-dark(var(--mantine-color-gray-3), var(--mantine-color-dark-4));
}

I’ve tried resetting cache, changing the imports to absolute paths, deleting and reinstalling node_modules, turning off strict mode, updating packages but to no avail.
